# RetroFit passing base url as variable

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit2

I have created a flutter web application using retrofit for consuming API. I am stuck with the issue of passing baseUrl as a variable to Retrofit which takes only const value. Base URL is different for different Environments.

```
final String apiDomain = globalWebApiUrl;
@RestApi(baseUrl: apiDomain);
```

This is throwing error:

`Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.`

Answer (score 2):

You can change class declaration by following.

```dart
@RestApi()
abstract class ApiService {
    factory ApiService({required Dio dio}) => _ApiService(dio);
}

// Use api service:

final String apiDomain = globalWebApiUrl;

final service = ApiService(dio: Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: apiDomain)));
```

Comment: This throws error of `Error: The non-abstract class '_ApiService' is missing implementations for these members:
 - ApiService.service

Comment: You will need to regerate code using build_runner. and also variable "service" is not member of ApiService class.

Comment: ok got it. Could you help me with where to use this 'service' variable now

Comment: You can create that variable where ever you want to make an api call.